# ASP.NET Core services.AddScoped In ConfigureServices Startup method

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a Data Access interface and class. IMyData implemented with MyData.
MyData has a constructor which takes a string which is the DB Connection String.
What is the correct method for configuring the ASP.NET IOC container.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddScoped<IMyData,new MyData(connStr)>();
    }
```

This is not correct. How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
services.AddScoped<IMyData>(provider=>
    return new MyData(connStr);
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately:

services.AddScoped(YourClient => new YourClient("https://clienturl/", new HttpClient()));

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.